# Why is this aggregate query returning one less row than it should?

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have the classic 'get all rows in one table with number of corresponding rows in another table' issue which should be solved by this query:

```
SELECT
    ideas.id,
    ideas.idea,
    submitted,
    COUNT(votes.id) AS vote_count
FROM ideas
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON ideas.id = votes.idea
WHERE dead = 0
GROUP BY votes.idea
ORDER BY vote_count DESC, submitted DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

There are 4 rows (with dead = 0) in ideas and one row in votes (relating to the first idea). However this query returns two records (idea #1 and idea #2) with correct vote_counts. Why is this not returning all of the records in ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `GROUP BY votes.idea`, you are asking for one result row per idea value in votes.  Since you say votes has only one row, you should expect only two records in the result — one corresponding to the idea value in that row of votes, and the other with NULL (condensing the three rows with no matching vote record).

Did you mean `GROUP BY ideas.idea`?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
GROUP BY votes.idea
```

to:

```
GROUP BY ideas.id
```

Because `votes.idea` can be NULL.